# &amp special character issue in json string

Tags: php, objective-c, json, url, nsstring

I have an array of dictionary converted into JSON string like this,

```
 NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    NSMutableDictionary *temp1= [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [temp setObject:@"item1" forKey:@"notes"];
    NSMutableDictionary *temp2= [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [temp2 setObject:@"item & item2 " forKey:@"notes"];

    NSString *json = [self aryToJSONString:allSync];
```

json converter:

```
-(NSString *)aryToJSONString:(id) ary{

NSError *error; 
NSString *jsonString;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:ary 
                                                   options:0 // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   }
    return jsonString;
}
```

Converted JSON:

```
[{"notes":"item"},{"notes":"item1 & item2"}]
```

and then POST it to the server (PHP). The server receives unparsable json string like this,

```
[{\"notes\":\" item1 \"},{\"notes\":\"item1 ","item2\"}]":"
```

How can I handle `&amp` special character issue?

**EDIT:**

PHP Code:

```
 $json = $_REQUEST['json'];
       $json = stripslashes($json);
       $jsonArr = json_decode($json, true);

       while($item = array_shift($jsonArr))
       {
           foreach($item as $key=>$value)
           {
           }
       }
```

Comment: try to use string replace like this `str_replace('&','&amp;',$string)`

Comment: can you share your php code?

Comment: PHP code shared please check @Mubashar Abbas

Comment: why are you doing stripslashes($json).. did you try echoing the $json before doing anything else?

Comment: @Mubashar Abbas i echoed json before  stripslashes($json) it cut off the after '&' symbol like  [{\"notes\":\" item1 \"},{\"notes\":\"item1

Comment: How do you send the the request?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

Pass JSON string to below method before posting to server.

```
-(NSString*)replaceSpecialCharsFromString:(NSString*)str
{
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];
    return str;
}
```